# Can you set your default browser in Windows 10 with a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I am making a batch script to launch some programs on a computer at my university that I use for class. The Computer resets every night however have a folder that maintains persistence. I am making a batch script and I would like to open a website however the default browser is Edge and I would like to use Firefox, is there a way to change the default browser from the script?

Comment: Why can't you simply invoke Firefox explicitly? As in `firefox https://stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: I didn't think of that! I tried it and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the default browser in the script as follows for Firefox

```
start Firefox https://www.google.co.in/
```